# remove() making changes to main list?

Tags: python, list

See in this python code, i want to retain the list k so i initialized the list to l and make changes in l.
But when i use the remove() function on "l" list  changes are made in "k" also .

Can anyone tell why it is happening and any alternative? 
Is it something with remove function or i have done anything wrong in my code?

Thanks in advance.

```
k=[1,1,1,1,1]
l=k
comb=[1,1]
for i in comb:
   l.remove(i)
print(k) 
[output]:[1,1]
```

req output=[1,1,1,1,1]

Comment: See [this](https://jeffknupp.com/blog/2012/11/13/is-python-callbyvalue-or-callbyreference-neither/) for a decent overall explanation. `l=k` means that both `l` and `k` are exactly the same object with two names.

Comment: k=[1,1,1,1,1]
l=list(k)
comb=[1,1]
for i in comb:
   l.remove(i)
print(k)